# Get multiple tables data through Entity Framework with Generic Repository and Unit Of work

Tags: entity-framework, linq, generics, asp.net-mvc-5, unit-of-work

I am working on Web-API project and using Entity Framework with Generic Repository and Unit Of work. Basically i follow a tutorial for [**this**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990492/RESTful-Day-sharp-Enterprise-Level-Application).

Here is my table architecture.
[image]

**Entity**

```
    public class ProductEntity
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public string ProductImgName { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public int PrimaryCatId { get; set; }
        public int SecondaryCatId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public List<PrimaryProductEntity> objPrimaryProduct { get; set; }
        public List<SecondaryProductEntity> objSecondaryProduct { get; set; }
    }

    public class PrimaryProductEntity
    {
        public int PrimaryCatId { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryCatName { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondaryProductEntity
    {
        public int SecondaryCatId { get; set; }
        public string SecondaryCatName { get; set; }
        public int PrimaryCatId { get; set; }
    }
```

**Services Code**

```
        public IEnumerable<BusinessEntities.ProductEntity> GetAllProducts()
        {
            var products = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            var primaryProducts = _unitOfWork.PrimaryProductRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            var secondaryProducts = _unitOfWork.SecondaryProductRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            if (products.Any())
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<tblProduct, ProductEntity>();
                var proInfo = from P in products
                          join PP in primaryProducts on P.PrimaryCatId equals PP.PrimaryCatId
                          join SP in primaryProducts on P.SecondaryCatId equals SP.SecondaryCatId
                          select P;
                var productsModel = Mapper.Map<List<tblProduct>, List<ProductEntity>>(proInfo);//getting error
                return productsModel;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

i know my implementation is wrong, i don't know what to write in code for fetch data from multiple tables. Please help me.

**Required Data**

ProductID,ProductName, PrimaryCatName, SecondaryCatName,Price, Quantity

Comment: Aren't you missing `public List<SecondaryProductEntity> objSecondaryProduct {get;set;} ` in class `PrimaryProductEntity` . I am also a newbie in entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Product Entity class Doesn't require a `List<PrimaryProductEntity>` and `List<SecondaryProductEntity>`. I suppose according to your class diagram Each `Product` is associated with one `PrimaryProductEntity` and one  `SecondaryProductEntity`.

Once your model class is corrected, you would be able to access the properties of the navigation. I am not so good with writing a Query the way you want. But i hope you could get an idea of what you should be doing

Comment: so how i achieve this.

Comment: You should be able to access the Properties as `obj.PrimaryProductEntity.ProductName`

Comment: When you save a product into the database, I guess you select the Primary Product category and Secodary product category it belongs to. Then it this could be achieved.